# How to override Bootstrap variables in Vue workflow ( Vanilla Bootstrap )?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

The officially recommended way to customize / theme bootstrap is by overriding the bootstrap variables using sass. But how do I do this, or rather, how do I add this part of the process into the Vue webpack workflow ?

Googling led to try editing the **vue.config.js** file to add scss loader into webpack but I am unable to find the required file.

[This is the directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snU6U.png)

I have used vue-cli v3.4 to setup the project.

I am using vanilla bootstrap and not the bootstrap-vue components.

Comment: I think this gets you started. It looks like @Ohgodwhy's answer is in keeping with this.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults

Comment: Yes I've read this part of the bootstrap docs but I want to include this in my vue project, for which I need to configure webpack. That's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make a file called `custom.scss`. Go into the `node_modules/bootstrap/scss` directory and copy everything from `_variables.scss`. Paste these into your `custom.scss`.

In your `style.scss` import your `custom.scss` before you import `bootstrap.scss`.

Now in your `main.js` import `@/assets/style.scss`.

You will need to remove the `!default` flag from any variables you wish to override in your `custom.scss` for them to take effect, as well.

Comment: But the thing is I need to configure webpack to set up the scss loader and compiler.  don't know where to find the file to put these config settings.

Comment: @KaustabhKakoty No, you don't. You said you're using `vue-cli`, there's no need to add that loader with my method. `vue-cli` includes this loader for you by default. Along with many, many more.run [vue-cli-serve inspect](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-inspect) and you'll see this.

Comment: yes this method worked. just added the sass loader to the dev dependencies and followed the method in the answer. works perfect. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

Create a file `/css/bootstrap-custom.scss`, with the following:

```
// your variable overrides
// modify theme colors map
$theme-colors: (
    "primary":#42b883,
    //...other variables, you can find them in node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss
);

// import to set changes
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

In the `main` script, import the added file instead of the current imported bootstrap css file:

```js
// import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import '@/css/bootstrap-custom.scss';
```

Reference: [Bootstrap, Variable defaults](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/theming/#variable-defaults)

Comment: What if you want to use something like `"primary": $pink`? It doesn't work since `$pink` is not available prior to importing so is there a way to solve this?