# Can I import sass file into main.js and make it global accessable?

Tags: vue.js, sass, sass-loader

I am using @vue/cli 4.5.8; "sass-loader": "^8.0.2"

I am trying to make an scss file globally accessible in the vue project.

I made a scss file called `style.scss`. This file include `varible.scss`, `mixin.scss` and `bootstrap.scss`. All sass files are in `/scss` folder.

Now in My `main.js` I `import "./scss/style.scss"`. But it doesn't work. I got **sass error: variable undefined.**

I know we can use sass-loader to make the style.scss globally available by [setup vue.config.js](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#passing-options-to-pre-processor-loaders), but I just want to know could this method work, because I've see people on the stackoverflow mentioned this [approch.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54829710/how-to-override-bootstrap-variables-in-vue-workflow-vanilla-bootstrap)

Comment: When global styles are imported via vue.config.js, they are actually injected implicitly in all your components. That's why you can use the variables everywhere. But that also means that all your variables, mixins, etc are replicated many times, be aware of that!. When importing SASS files in main.js, they are simply compiled into CSS. So i think the answer is no

Comment: @Serg - do you mean, when I put sass in main.js, it is available for all components, but it becomes css, so the sass variable doesn't work. and I  get an error for that. And what do you think about a better approach of manage sass files in Vue cli project? Thanks!

Comment: no, importing the SASS file in main.js does not make variables, mixins etc. available globally. In my projects, I create a SCSS file (e.g. vars.scss) with all the globals and import it in vue.config.js as recommended in the link you mentioned. This works always absolutely fine for me

Comment: but I imported bootstrap.scss from node_modules in the `main.js`, and I can use bootstrap styles in all components. I just don't understand why import from /src folder (./scss/style.scss) doesn't work. It might be the webpack configuration I guess.

Comment: yes, of course, by importing `bootstrap.scss` in `main.js` all styles are applied. When you run `npm run serve`, SASS is compiled to CSS, all variables are resolved and the styles added to your site. But your components still does not know anything about the bootsrap SASS variables. You have to either import `bootstrap.scss` in each component manually where you want to use variables or to setup `vue.config.js`

Comment: I did a test on it, and you're absolutely right about it! BTW, you're really good at Vue's rule. What resource do you use to learn it besides the documentation?

Comment: I've read a lot in 2+ years of working with Vue, it's hard to name anything specific. Just solve problems as they arise. I have also learned a lot by creating a custom Vue plugin. Your question is also not really Vue specific, it's more build tools (like Webpack) and SASS itself related.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I need to learn more about the build tools.